# authorization header in https request

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, https

Firstly, sorry for my grammar mistakes, I'm a Chinese who cannot find an answer in the Chinese community, so I search for help here. Please help me, thanks!

### 1 Problem

Simply put, I use HTTPAnalyzer to trace an https request, and this request contains a header named authentication (I have put this header at the end of this post)

So the problem is that, If I resend this https request, it returns a 401 error. But if I tick off "Auto Authentication" like this:

[HTTPAnalyzer Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSuxL.png)

The request builder just worked out! The server responded correctly!

So I'm totally confused, what did HTTPAnalyzer do to deal with authentication?

### 2、the way I have tried to find answer

Firstly I checked these two requests sent by HTTPAnalyzer request builder.I didn't tick off that option in the first one.The thing is that, although all data(header and body)I put in request builder are the same, HTTPAnalyzer automatically changed this authorization header when I ticked off "Auto Authentication".some part of this header changed but the whole header is encoded, so I don't know how it changed.

Then I tried to decode this.I searched on Google, knowing that this header is commonly encoded in base64. However, I tried to decode this header, but it turned out to be random characters and have no meaning.

So I am really confused.Please help me to decode this header and tell me how to handle this authorization process.

So many thanks!

### I 'll paste this header below:

Authorization: Negotiate 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